# XML De/Serialization : How to define different name for same property of different instance of the class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm trying to serialize an object which contains two lists of the same object.

```
public class Foo
{
   public List<ClassA> DataA {get;set;}
   public List<ClassA> DataB {get;set;}
}

public class ClassA
{
  public string Code {get;set;}
  public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

In the xml file I would like that the properties of the class have different name. Something like this :

```
<Foo>
  <DataA>
    <ClassA>
      <Code></Code>
      <Value></Value>
    </ClassA>
  </DataA>
  <DataB>
    <ClassA>
      <Name></Name>
      <Text></Text>
    </ClassA>
  </DataB>
</Foo>
```

I tried to use "XmlAttributeOverrides" but the property name is modified for all instance, not just one.

Is there a way to do this ? Maybe a custom XmlSerializer ?

Thanks

Comment: Use different classes? Obviously the generalize something they shouldn't.

Comment: just a shot in the dark, you do not close ``<DataA>`` and ``<DataB>``properly. Is this in your local code also?

Comment: @dba : No, it's just an error in this post ;)

Comment: @Fildor : It's a generic class that just have 2 properties that I use for different purpose. 
In my example I have 2 lists but I can have 5, 6 or more.
So, if it's possible, I prefer not create a new class each time and just have one.

Comment: Well, a generic model creates generic XML ... now you _could_ probably do some fancy code-magic, maybe using annotations/attributes, or you serialize generic and run a post-production XSLT that renames tags ... all in all, I personally would go for a decent model. But if that's not an option for you, then you'll probably have to live with the caveats.

Comment: @BahaBulle ClassA doesn't seem to be ``generic`` (see: [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes)), but a common-used one.... Right?

Comment: @dba : That's right

Comment: So to reuse ClassA, decorating the list props with ArrayAttribute (see bottom of my Answer) should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Copy the input XML into your Clipboard

```
<Foo>
  <DataA>
    <ClassA>
      <Code></Code>
      <Value></Value>
    </ClassA>
    <ClassA>
      <Code></Code>
      <Value></Value>
    </ClassA>
  </DataA>
  <DataB>
    <ClassA>
      <Name></Name>
      <Text></Text>
    </ClassA>
    <ClassA>
        <Code></Code>
        <Value></Value>
    </ClassA>
  </DataB>
</Foo>
```

and in Visual Studio add a new class file to your project.
Select and clear all content of the newly created file  inside the namespace an use `Edit->paste Special->insert XML as code` (or something similar, I have a german IDE)

[image]

should give you something like this (after some reorganizing)

```
namespace SandBoxApp
{

  // HINWEIS: Für den generierten Code ist möglicherweise mindestens .NET Framework 4.5 oder .NET Core/Standard 2.0 erforderlich.
  /// <remarks/>
  [System.SerializableAttribute()]
  [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
  public partial class Foo
  {

    private FooClassA[] dataAField;

    private FooClassA[] dataBField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("ClassA", IsNullable = false)]
    public FooClassA[] DataA
    {
      get
      {
        return this.dataAField;
      }
      set
      {
        this.dataAField = value;
      }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("ClassA", IsNullable = false)]
    public FooClassA[] DataB
    {
      get
      {
        return this.dataBField;
      }
      set
      {
        this.dataBField = value;
      }
    }
  }

  /// <remarks/>
  [System.SerializableAttribute()]
  [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
  public partial class FooClassA
  {

    private object codeField;

    private object valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public object Code
    {
      get
      {
        return this.codeField;
      }
      set
      {
        this.codeField = value;
      }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public object Value
    {
      get
      {
        return this.valueField;
      }
      set
      {
        this.valueField = value;
      }
    }
  }
```

You may want to refactor to your needs, but it should give you the direction.

To sum up,  I think you miss the Attribute:

```
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("ClassA", IsNullable = false)]
```

on your list-Poperties